# How to fix "System services not available to Activities before onCreate" when passing values between classes, and updating recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-strictmode

I'm making an order taking cashier application. Using a recycler view to show the order queue. However, I'm having trouble passing ArrayList values between classes, and also, updating the recycler view. In this case, I won't have a massive recycler view so performance wouldn't be that much of an issue, but an optimized method of doing this would be greatly appreciated. I just don't know how to tackle this problem.

I've attempted to create a set method in the MainActivty class, I've also tried the intent put extra, but I don't believe I fully understand put extra quite yet.

MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public  ArrayList<String> orderList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // set up the RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyle_view_activity);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, orderList);
        ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setClickListener(this);


        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));


        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }

    //This is the set method I attempted:
    public void setOrderAdd(ArrayList<String> data){
        if (data != null){
           mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this,data); //Error refrences here
        }
    }
}
```

Other Class:

```
public class regularCoffee extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, Serializable {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_regular_coffee);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        addToOrder();

}

public void addToOrder(){
        //Reg Addons:
        final CheckBox leaveRoomReg = findViewById(R.id.leave_room_reg);
        final CheckBox cinnamonReg = findViewById(R.id.cinnamon_reg);
        final CheckBox chocolateSyrupReg = findViewById(R.id.chocolate_syrup_reg);
        final CheckBox whiteChocolateSyrupReg = findViewById(R.id.white_chocolate_syrup_reg);
        final CheckBox caramelReg = findViewById(R.id.caramelReg);
        final CheckBox hazelnutReg = findViewById(R.id.hazel_nut_reg);

        final CheckBox[] RegCoffeeAddOns = {leaveRoomReg,cinnamonReg,chocolateSyrupReg,whiteChocolateSyrupReg,caramelReg,hazelnutReg};

        //Decaf Addons:
        final Button leaveRoomDecaf = findViewById(R.id.leave_room_decaf);
        final Button cinnamonDecaf = findViewById(R.id.cinnamon_decaf);
        final Button chocolateSyrupDecaf = findViewById(R.id.chocolate_syrup_decaf);
        final Button whiteChocolateDecaf = findViewById(R.id.white_chocolate_syrup_decaf);
        final Button caramelDecaf = findViewById(R.id.caramel_decaf);
        final Button hazelnutDecaf = findViewById(R.id.hazel_nut_decaf);

        final Button[] DecafCoffeeAddOns = {leaveRoomDecaf,cinnamonDecaf,caramelDecaf,chocolateSyrupDecaf,whiteChocolateDecaf,hazelnutDecaf};

        Button addToOrderButton = findViewById(R.id.addToOrderReg);



        addToOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity addToOrderArea = new MainActivity();
                String forOrder;
                ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();

                if (regCoffeeQuantity > 0){
                    forOrder = "Regular Coffee (x" + regCoffeeQuantity + ") \n   ";
                    for (int i = 0; i < RegCoffeeAddOns.length; i++){
                        if (RegCoffeeAddOns[i].isChecked()){
                            forOrder = forOrder + "| " + RegCoffeeAddOns[i].getText().toString() + " ";
                            System.out.println(forOrder);
                        }
                    }

                   addToOrderArea.setOrderAdd(tempArray); //Error refrences here

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
package com.example.holygroundsapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); //Error refrences here.
        this.mData = data;
    }


    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalName);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(MainActivity itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5774)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:233)
        at com.example.holygroundsapplication.MyRecyclerViewAdapter.<init>(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java:21)
        at com.example.holygroundsapplication.MainActivity.setOrderAdd(MainActivity.java:89)
        at com.example.holygroundsapplication.regularCoffee$8.onClick(regularCoffee.java:262)
...
```

Comment: I solved this issue by using Fragments instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick` function you have

> `MainActivity addToOrderArea = new MainActivity();`

You shouldn't create activity instances by your self. This is something the Android system does. Because you create the activity by yourself it is not initialized (i.e. `onCreate()` is not called). The adapter which is created in the `setOrderAdd()` requires that the Activity is initialized and therefore throws an exception.

To prevent these problems you need to create your Activity with `startActivity()`. You can pass your data to the new Activity by adding extras to the starting Intent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you logically need to replace

`MainActivity addToOrderArea = new MainActivity();`

with

`MainActivity addToOrderArea = MainActivity.this;`

But since you are not in the same class you need to pass the reference accordingly. 
As long the MainActivity is still active and the other class is just a helper that wouldn't be a problem. Just add MainActivity to all the constructors... Somewhat like this:

```
OtherClass{
    private MainClass addToOrderArea;
    public OtherClass(MainClass addToOrderArea){
        this.addToOrderArea=addToOrderArea;
    }

    // ...

    abstract class MyOnclicklistener extends View.OnClickListene{
        private MainClass addToOrderArea;
        public MyOnclicklistener(MainClass addToOrderArea){
            this.addToOrderArea=addToOrderArea;
        }
    }

    // ...

    addToOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnclicklistener(this.addToOrderArea) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String forOrder;
            ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();

            if (regCoffeeQuantity > 0){
                forOrder = "Regular Coffee (x" + regCoffeeQuantity + ") \n   ";
                for (int i = 0; i < RegCoffeeAddOns.length; i++){
                    if (RegCoffeeAddOns[i].isChecked()){
                        forOrder = forOrder + "| " + RegCoffeeAddOns[i].getText().toString() + " ";
                        System.out.println(forOrder);
                    }
                }

               addToOrderArea.setOrderAdd(tempArray); //Error refrences here

            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Attention: i guess this might still get you into another error, since you try to edit one activity from another...**

Propably only store the variable between both activities, that seems okay. Updating the recycler view directly from another activity however might get you into some android view or security errors. I would say just pass the variable and update the recyclerview in the onResume function later. Something like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> _data;

public void setOrderAdd(ArrayList<String> data){
    if (data != null){
        // only store variable
        _data = data;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // make update of your viewing components here
    if(_data!=null){
        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this,_data);
    }
}
```

**Now it should work i guess**

Comment: Hi zeg! Thanks for answering, I had to change the abstract class to "implements" to run it, but now I get this error whenever I open up the page for the other class:
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.holygroundsapplication, PID: 1228
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.holygroundsapplication/com.example.holygroundsapplication.regularCoffee}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.holygroundsapplication.regularCoffee> has no zero argument constructor
`

Comment: Hi @StyleOver i would suggest to find this line ```... = new regularCoffee()``` and remove it. it is kinda the same as your previous ```... = new MainActivity()```, however you can fix it by either creating the new instance correctly (but that is possibly not what you want) or you pass your object down to the class where you need it.